# How to insert array (that varies) to mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array `$workCard = $_POST['rep_list'];` I want to insert the array into my **mySQL** table `task`. 
 The challenge for me is that the array can vary, meaning sometimes the array can contain `user:id, customer_id, tire, hub, break_adjust` and sometimes it contains less, more and different values - it varies from array to array and since it varies I can not get a grip on how to insert it to my table `task` 
Ps. arrays always contains `user_id` and `customer_id`.

I need your suggestions on how to insert my array?

**My insert-data.php file**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['rep_list'])) {
  $workCard = $_POST['rep_list'];
//Insert into table TASK
//This is as far as I get since I have no idea on how to proceed inserting my array 
?>
```

**Here is what an ARRAY can look like (remember my array's vary, this is just one ex.):**

```
Array
(
    [pickup] => 2014/11/07 15:45
    [tire_back] => tire_back
    [tire_reg] => tire_reg
    [hub_adjust] => hub_adjust
    [rim_adjust] => rim_adjust
    [break_pad_back] => break_pad_back
    [crankset] => crankset
    [crank] => crank
    [price_max] => 
    [price_approx] => 
    [service_1] => 1
    [service_2] => 2
    [service_3] => 3
    [service_4] => 4
    [message] => 
    [user] => 2
    [0] => 40405553

)
```

**My TASK table looks like this:**

```
CREATE TABLE `task` (
  `task_id` int(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(40) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(40) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `tire` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tube` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `hub` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `rim` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `spoke` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `break_adjust` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `break_cable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `break_pad` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `gear_adj` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `gear_cable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `gear_shift` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `bicy_chain` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `cog_wheel` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `cassette` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `chainwheel` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `crankset` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `crank` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `fp_service` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `price_max` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `price_approx` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `service` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `pickup` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `task_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `task_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You can write one query that will insert all columns and just account for blank values.

Comment: Enter the value you need and let others values blank ? ( put all possibility into the db ) p.s you will need to change the not null default

Comment: @jay-blanchard blank or `NULL`?

Comment: Actually I would account for both.

Comment: if it is really flexible (ie, columns pretty much infinitely variable) I would be tempted to redesign the table, splitting each field off to a different row on another table. But if those values have a pretty direct relationship with the table columns then I would just loop around the array to build up the relevant insert statement.

Comment: @Kickstart can you give me ex. of how you would make the loop for my above code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want flexibility between the names of the form fields and the fields on the table (and I am not quite sure how those match up in the example data you have given), then I would do the following.

I would have an array of each field, each element of which is an array of details of the field. For each input element loop through the fields until you get the one that matches that element and assign the value (if not found the default values will be used later).

Once that is done you can use these values as parameters for the actual insert statement.

You could do this a few different ways to suit you. for example you could swap around whether the array is keyed by the input name or the field name.

Something like this:-

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

if (isset($_POST['rep_list'])) 
{
    $workCard = $_POST['rep_list'];

    $field_list = array('task_id'=>array('in_name'=>'task_id', 'value'=>"NULL"),
                         'user_id'=>array('in_name'=>'user_id', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'customer_id'=>array('in_name'=>'customer_id', 'value'=>"''"),
                         'created'=>array('in_name'=>'created', 'value'=>"''"),
                         'tire'=>array('in_name'=>'tire', 'value'=>"''"),
                         'tube'=>array('in_name'=>'tube', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'hub'=>array('in_name'=>'hub', 'value'=>"''"),
                         'rim'=>array('in_name'=>'rim', 'value'=>"''"),
                         'spoke'=>array('in_name'=>'spoke', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'break_adjust'=>array('in_name'=>'break_adjust', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'break_cable'=>array('in_name'=>'break_cable', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'break_pad'=>array('in_name'=>'break_pad', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'gear_adj'=>array('in_name'=>'gear_adj', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'gear_cable'=>array('in_name'=>'gear_cable', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'gear_shift'=>array('in_name'=>'gear_shift', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'bicy_chain'=>array('in_name'=>'bicy_chain', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'cog_wheel'=>array('in_name'=>'cog_wheel', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'cassette'=>array('in_name'=>'cassette', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'chainwheel'=>array('in_name'=>'chainwheel', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'crankset'=>array('in_name'=>'crankset', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'crank'=>array('in_name'=>'crank', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'fp_service'=>array('in_name'=>'fp_service', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'price_max'=>array('in_name'=>'price_max', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'price_approx'=>array('in_name'=>'price_approx', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'service'=>array('in_name'=>'service', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'status'=>array('in_name'=>'status', 'value'=>"0"),
                         'pickup'=>array('in_name'=>'pickup', 'value'=>"''"));

    foreach($workCard AS $workCard_key=>$workCard_value)
    {
        foreach($field_list AS $field_list_key=>$field_list_value)
        {
            if ($field_list_value['in_name'] == $workCard_key)
            {
                $field_list_value['value'] = $workCard_value;
            }
        }
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO task (user_id,
                             customer_id,
                             created,
                             tire,
                             tube,
                             hub,
                             rim,
                             spoke,
                             break_adjust,
                             break_cable,
                             break_pad,
                             gear_adj,
                             gear_cable,
                             gear_shift,
                             bicy_chain,
                             cog_wheel,
                             cassette,
                             chainwheel,
                             crankset,
                             crank,
                             fp_service,
                             price_max,
                             price_approx,
                             service,
                             status,
                             pickup)
            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bind_param('iiississiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiis', $field_list['user_id']['value'],
                          $field_list['customer_id']['value'],
                          $field_list['created']['value'],
                          $field_list['tire']['value'],
                          $field_list['tube']['value'],
                          $field_list['hub']['value'],
                          $field_list['rim']['value'],
                          $field_list['spoke']['value'],
                          $field_list['break_adjust']['value'],
                          $field_list['break_cable']['value'],
                          $field_list['break_pad']['value'],
                          $field_list['gear_adj']['value'],
                          $field_list['gear_cable']['value'],
                          $field_list['gear_shift']['value'],
                          $field_list['bicy_chain']['value'],
                          $field_list['cog_wheel']['value'],
                          $field_list['cassette']['value'],
                          $field_list['chainwheel']['value'],
                          $field_list['crankset']['value'],
                          $field_list['crank']['value'],
                          $field_list['fp_service']['value'],
                          $field_list['price_max']['value'],
                          $field_list['price_approx']['value'],
                          $field_list['service']['value'],
                          $field_list['status']['value'],
                          $field_list['pickup']['value']);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
```